# Using JSON extract where data has no key

Tags: mysql, database

My data:

```
 ["2016-04-21", "2016-04-22"]
```

My Query:

```
select * from applications WHERE JSON_CONTAINS("date", "$");
```

My json data do not have keys, show how I can use `JSON_CONTAINS` here?

Comment: What you call *My JSON data* is not a JSON data. You cannot treat any kind of data as one, indeed.

Comment: @vahdet Column type is JSON and have already records, so I can not do anything beside working what it is?

Comment: @vahdet actually the dates are getting saved by using json_encode($dates) in php which is a numerical array. maybe this information will give better idea to my problem.

Comment: @Nick so now what could be the solution?

Comment: @Sumankumarpanda does the posted answer not do what you want?

Comment: @Nick it seems okay, but can not we use `JSON_CONTAINS`, it is seems good, that is why i upvoted.

Comment: @Sumankumarpanda no, you can't use `JSON_CONTAINS` in this scenario because you need to use a wildcard path (`$[*]`) which is not permitted by `JSON_CONTAINS`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you want to find a date value in your JSON data you can use the following using [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM applications 
WHERE NOT JSON_SEARCH(col_json, 'one', '2016-04-22') IS NULL;
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7efed48dd5b35cc9c5efd7291eb0c835)

---

**Why you can't use `JSON_CONTAINS`?**

To search a specific date value in your JSON data you need to use a wildcard (`*`). This isn't allowed on the `JSON_CONTAINS` path argument:

> An error occurs if target or candidate is not a valid JSON document, or if the path argument is not a valid path expression or contains a * or ** wildcard.

Comment: Personally I find `IS NOT NULL` easier to read than `NOT ... IS NULL` but this is definitely the right answer for this problem. Also you could use `one` rather than `all` to save time searching for other matches when you only need to find one.

Comment: Thank you for answer Sebastian, can I use multiple dates and check if any of dates match or I need to use OR clauses?

Comment: @Sumankumarpanda - You need to use `OR` to search for multiple date values.